# ABCPdf library - parallel processing

Tags: c#, .net, abcpdf, abcpdf9

Have any of you tried to convert *.docx file into *.pdf using ABCPdf library in parallel loop?

Here is my method that is called in Parallel.ForEach loop

```
public void ConvertDocxToPdf(string fileIn, string fileOut)
{
    var theDoc = new Doc();
    theDoc.Read(fileIn);
    theDoc.Save(fileOut);
    theDoc.Clear();
}
```

It appears to be slow. I have 8 cores but only 6 of them are used. Average CPU usage is 18%.

Comment: Are you asking if performance can be improved?  Or how to use more cores?  Do you want CPU usage to be higher or lower?

Comment: I'd like to improve performance, specifically increase the number of parallel conversions. It's strange that when I run 8 threads ABCPdf uses only 6 cores at once.